# nginx alias php 403

Tags: php, nginx, alias

My webroot is /web/zjz, I want use http://new.ahsl.gov.cn/zjz/ to browse,but responses 403, I don't know where is the error, pls help me, thanks
the nginx config is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  new.ahsl.gov.cn www.ahsl.gov.cn;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/www.test.gov.cn_access.log  main;
    root   /web/master;

    location ^~ /zjz/ {
        alias /web/zjz;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /web/zjz/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    include /web/master/.htaccess;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.(jpg|png|gif)$ {
        expires 1h;
        gzip on;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of ```/var/log/nginx/error.log```?

Comment: 2018/11/16 12:00:38 [error] 1268#1268: *17 directory index of "/home/html/xnjcy/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.0.101, server: www.test.gov.cn, request: "GET /xnjcy/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.test.gov.cn"

Comment: There a a number of problems with your configuration, but the error message in your comment does not match the configuration - there is no `root /home/html` or `location /xnjcy`. The 403 response simply means that Nginx did not find an `index.html` file within that directory.